# PHP Object Equality for Nested Objects

Tags: php, oop, reflection, identity, equality

Is there any stand alone code, or a library in a stand alone framework that can be used for comparing PHP objects that contain other object references?

The [equality](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.object-comparison.php) operator can be used to test object **identity**.  I'm looking for code that would let me do something like this

```
$a = new Foo;
$b = new Foo;

if(objectsAreEqual($a,b)
{
}
```

I know I could use something like this

```
get_object_vars($a) == get_object_vars($b)
```

or some other form of reflection to compare properties, but if the object contains a nested object, we're back to the identity problem.

So, before I attempt to implement myself, I've like to know is this is a solved problem anywhere

Comment: You want to check entities AND values? Is performance a big issue? Perhaps you could consider `serialize($a)==serialize($b)`?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a way to do this without recursion:

```
function objectsAreEqual($a, $b) {
    $aProps = get_object_vars($a);
    $bProps = get_object_vars($b);


    foreach($aProps as $k => $v) {
        // check if key exists in b
        if(!isset($bProps[$k]) { 
            return false; 
        }

        // check if they're equal (if not an object or array)
        if($v != $bProps[$k]) {
            return false;
        }

        // if $v is an object or array
        if(is_object($v) || is_array($v)) {
            return objectsAreEqual($v, $bProps[$k]);
        }  

    }   

    return true;
}
```

Be sure to test this, but I think it should work. If you need to fix it before it works, please edit the code here too.